# WordPress menu position

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am running a website using WordPress and using some javascript that changes the page see http://s72956.gridserver.com/dev/.

I want my menu position to be static at 150px down and 800px right and not move when I change my browser window to any size. Currently when I try `position:static;` it moves when I click on one of my javascript links that expands a section. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

In your css, try `position: fixed;` instead of using `position:absolute;`.

Comment: changed it but it still moves.